# How to pipe multiple exe files then output result to file?

Tags: powershell

I want to merge two json files, then transform output into yaml and output it into file. My current code (which is not working):

```
param($parentJson, $childJson)

$cmdPath = "$PSScriptRoot\jq-win64.exe"
$cmdArgList = @(
    "-s",
    ".[0] * .[1]",
    "$parentJson"
    "$childJson"
)

$cmdPath2 = "$PSScriptRoot\yq_windows_386.exe"
$cmdArgList2 = @(
    "eval",
    "-P",
    "-o=yaml"
)

$resultJson = (cmd /c $cmdPath $cmdArgList 2>&1) -join "`r`n" 

$resultYaml = $resultJson > (cmd /c $cmdPath2 $cmdArgList2)

$resultYaml
```

How to pipe two executable with multiple arguments into file? Honestly this is only thing I thought will be easy to do in powershell, but I don't have enough experience to comprehend why everything so hard when you work with executable stdin/stdout and just want to pipe one into another.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy solution:

```
param($parentJson, $childJson, $outputYaml)

.\jq-win64.exe -s '.[0] * .[1]' $parentJson $childJson | .\yq_windows_386.exe eval -P -o=yaml - > $outputYaml
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).